# How can I make the effects of the source light disappear?

Tags: objects, lighting

[image]I am trying to remove the shadow effect on this object that i created, so that i can see it as if there was no light source, how can i do that? You can see that the right side are darker than the others, how can I make this effect disappear?
Thank you in advance to anyone willing to help!

Comment: Hello, you could use an Emission node, but the more it will be powerful, the less you'll see the volume, no shadow means no visible volume

Answer (score 0):

In object's shader just plug your `Texture`'s `Color` (or anything coming into `Principled BSDF`'s `Base Color` input) output directly into `Material Output`'s `Surface` input, bypassing `Principled BSDF`.

[image]